# Change a google sheet move script from on edit to manual

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to change an OnEdit Script into a manually run script.

The google script below works on Edit for copying a specific range of data (B:AJ) based on a "Y" being placed on AK to another spreadsheet with "BZ" spliced in, then moving the original row to another sheet within the same workbook. With it being based onEdit, it is causing the user to wait for the script to run before putting a "Y" in the next row. I would like to convert it to a manually run script that uses the menu function I already have available.

OnEdit Script:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var sourceSheetName = "Bretts Calendar with Accounting";
  var destinationSpreadsheetId = '1dSJOOw_oLVc6Nf-C0MY9715tZGuh69kR6-j_m8EJ-So';
  var destinationSheetName = "Unprocessed Acct Data";

  if (e.source.getSheetName() == sourceSheetName && e.range.getColumn() == 37 && e.value.toUpperCase() == "Y") {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
    var sourceValues = e.source.getRange("B" + row + ":AK" + row).getValues()[0];
  var values = [sourceValues.slice(0, 35)];
  values[0].unshift("BZ");
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheetId);
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow() + 1, 2, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  e.range.setValue("Copied");
  var destSheetName = "Reviewed Bretts Calendar with Accounting";
  var destSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(destSheetName);
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1, 1, e.source.getActiveSheet().getLastColumn()).moveTo(destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1 , 1, 1, e.source.getActiveSheet().getLastColumn()));
    var destinationRange = ts.getRange("A2:AK");
    destinationRange.sort([{column: 6, ascending: true}, {column: 7, ascending: true}]); 
    e.source.getActiveSheet().deleteRow(e.range.getRow());  
}
}
```

I know how to add the script to a drop down menu which allows it to be manually run but I am lost on how to reference which row(s) for the script to grab as it is no longer on edit and if I need to loop the script so it catches all the lines 1 by 1 or if it has the ability to see all the rows and handle the copy, and move all at once.

```
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'Send Data', functionName: 'sendData_'},
         ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Click Me', menuItems);
}

function sendData_(){
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Bretts Calendar with Accounting');
    var destinationSpreadsheetId = '1dSJOOw_oLVc6Nf-C0MY9715tZGuh69kR6-j_m8EJ-So';
    var destinationSheetName = "Unprocessed Acct Data";
    s.getRange('B:AK').getValues().forEach(function (r,i){
    if (r[36] == "y" || r[36] == "Y") {
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var sourceValues = e.source.getRange("B" + row + ":AK" + row).getValues()[0];
  var values = [sourceValues.slice(0, 35)];
  values[0].unshift("BZ");

  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheetId);
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow() + 1, 2, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  e.range.setValue("Copied");
  var destSheetName = "Reviewed Bretts Calendar with Accounting";
  var destSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(destSheetName);
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1, 1, e.source.getActiveSheet().getLastColumn()).moveTo(destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1 , 1, 1, e.source.getActiveSheet().getLastColumn()));
    var destinationRange = ts.getRange("A2:AK");
    destinationRange.sort([{column: 6, ascending: true}, {column: 7, ascending: true}]); 
    e.source.getActiveSheet().deleteRow(e.range.getRow());  
}
    }
  }
```

I have created to links to help:

[Calendar](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qv9UidR5WJY6wDMli8yC1jY6gX1FROrgfHZKsdmOfI0/edit?usp=sharing)

[Acct](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15r1WyUjjURr0KlsSU_GsuR3GOivBi37pEWXjIxKI5zw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The post is too broad as it includes two question. This site requieres one question per post. Ref. [ask]. By the other hand, it's unclear as it doesn't clearly state where you are stuck. If you get an error message include it textually.

Comment: @Rubén I have excluded the second half and added more details. Hopefully it will be more clear now.

Comment: @Leilani How about `var currentCell = sheet.getCurrentCell();var currentRow = currentCell.getRow();var currentColumn = currentCell.getColumn();`? then take it from there.